# Error WeightNotComputable - XCM Transaction

Tags: parachain, xcm, weight, error, astar

I am getting the XCM error of [`WeightNotComputable`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/75a1bf47bd04c15be230bb09bb2c3d79de3db8b8/xcm/src/v3/traits.rs#L155). What could be the cause of this?

[image]

Here is the [XCM code](https://github.com/ok-Alice/Astar/blob/liquid-staking/pallets/nomination-pools-staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L221-L275) which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because you use instruction [`WithdrawAsset(1,Here)`](https://github.com/ok-Alice/Astar/blob/liquid-staking/pallets/nomination-pools-staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L254), but the relaychain [cannot handle this token](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.42/runtime/kusama/src/weights/xcm/mod.rs#L41), it only can handle the native token which is `(0, Here)`, this will [return Weight::MAX](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.42/runtime/kusama/src/weights/xcm/mod.rs#L82) when getting the weight of the instruction. Then cause the error `WeightNotComputable`.

Answer (score 0):

The `WeightNotComputable` error is returned as an `Err` from the `prepare` function below. The `Weighter::weight` function returns the maximum amount of weight that an attempted execution of this message could consume, so it seems like it has failed to infer the max weight.

```rust
fn prepare(
        mut message: Xcm<Config::RuntimeCall>,
    ) -> Result<Self::Prepared, Xcm<Config::RuntimeCall>> {
        match Config::Weigher::weight(&mut message) {
            Ok(weight) => Ok(WeighedMessage(weight, message)),
            Err(_) => Err(message),
        }
    }
```

Could you please check whether the weight is being loaded correctly in `#[pallet::weight(<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::WeightInfo::create_nomination_pool())]`?

Comment: How would go about validating that the weight is being loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/open-message-passing-channels/) you can checkout that Transact will execute the encoded call that you prepared on the relay chain.Please check the requireWeightAtMost to specify the maximum amount of weight to use in dispatching the XCM call.

[image]